# summing the contents of an array

Tags: mips

I'm having an issue summing the contents of an array while in a loop.

```
loop3:      
    beq $t5, $t1, loop4      #if $t5 is equal to $t1, then goto exit

    lw $t6, 0($s0)      #load contents of $s0 to $t6
    add $t6, $t6, $t6     #sums the contents

    addi $s0, $s0, 4      #increments pointer of pArry
    add $t5, $t5, 1      #increments counter of loop3
    j loop3
```

Answer (score 1):

You're not summing all the elements because you're overwriting `$t6` with the current array element at the beginning of each iteration: `lw $t6, 0($s0)      #load contents of $s0 to $t6`

Load the current element into some other (free) register instead:

```
lw $t7, 0($s0)      #load contents of $s0 to $t7
add $t6, $t6, $t7   #sums the contents
```

Make sure to clear `$t6` before the beginning of the loop.